# arabic text on wordpress site, double quotes in wrong direction

Tags: wordpress, arabic, wpml

I'm doing up a multilingual wordpress site using WPML. For arabic text on the wordpress site, double quotes show up as smart quotes in wrong direction. I tried to turn the smart quotes to straight quotes but doesn't work.

Is there a way to change the direction of the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by using arabic font